# Creating multiple dataframes at once using filter function in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to create 14 separate dataframes in order to run an ANOVA on each of them separately. (If there is a way to run 14 separate ANOVA's without creating these dataframes, please let me know.) I have a large, tidy dataframe with a column "number" that specifies the question number.

```
id  number  value
1   1       2
1   2       1
1   3       4
2   1       4
2   2       3
2   3       4
```

I know I could create individual dataframes one-by-one in the following way:

```
df1 <- filter(df, number == 1) 
df2 <- filter(df, number == 2) 
df3 <- filter(df, number == 3)
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of creating these dataframes.

Comment: `split` the data by `id` and apply the anova code. E.g. - `lapply(split(dat, dat$id), function(x) anova(lm(value ~ number, data=x)) )` or even `by` - `by(dat, dat$id, function(x) anova(lm(value ~ number, data=x)))` - not sure what the tidyverse equivalent is but I'm sure there is something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr::do`, we can easily do the calculation for each group. I also show the improved/standardised result if we use `broom::tidy` on the `anova` results (consistent variable names for one), see the [broom and dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html) for more.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_table2(
  "id  number  value
1   1       2
  1   2       1
  1   3       4
  2   1       4
  2   2       3
  2   3       4"
)

tbl %>%
  group_by(number) %>%
  do(anova(lm(value ~ number, data = .)))
#> Warning in anova.lm(lm(value ~ number, data = .)): ANOVA F-tests on an
#> essentially perfect fit are unreliable
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#> # Groups:   number [3]
#>   number    Df `Sum Sq` `Mean Sq` `F value` `Pr(>F)`
#>    <int> <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1      1     1 2.00e+ 0  2.00e+ 0        NA       NA
#> 2      2     1 2.00e+ 0  2.00e+ 0        NA       NA
#> 3      3     1 7.89e-31  7.89e-31        NA       NA

library(broom)
tbl %>%
  group_by(number) %>%
  do(tidy(anova(lm(value ~ number, data = .))))
#> Warning in anova.lm(lm(value ~ number, data = .)): ANOVA F-tests on an
#> essentially perfect fit are unreliable
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#> # Groups:   number [3]
#>   number term         df    sumsq   meansq statistic p.value
#>    <int> <chr>     <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1      1 Residuals     1 2.00e+ 0 2.00e+ 0        NA      NA
#> 2      2 Residuals     1 2.00e+ 0 2.00e+ 0        NA      NA
#> 3      3 Residuals     1 7.89e-31 7.89e-31        NA      NA
```

Created on 2018-04-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Does "number" need to be in the linear model? If I create a linear model and instead include two other columns, should it still work? Or do I need to include "number" if I am doing group_by(number) ?

Comment: No, so long as you are using columns that are in the data. putting `number` in `lm` is just an example

Comment: Second the recommendation for the broom & dplyr, and would also recommend the [many models](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) article from R for Data Science for a deep dive